# How to rotate Mobile device while testing using JAVA to landscape and portrait . I tried to use DesiredCapabilities but it didn't worked

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, selenium

Map<String, Object> mobileEmulator = new HashMap<String, Object>();

```
            mobileEmulator.put("deviceName", deviceName);

            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

            ChromeOptions chromeOption = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOption.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
            chromeOption.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulator);

            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setCapability("rotatable", true);
            caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", orientationMode);
            caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOption);

            chromeOption.merge(caps);

            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOption);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Note:** Changing the orientation of your mobile device can be done only before test execution starts, using a capability. The orientation cannot be changed in the middle of the test script. **Plus**, I'm not 100% sure, but selenium.dev didn't fully implement the orientation capability, they started it but it has now been superseded by Chrome DevTools on Selenium 4.0.0

Comment: I am able to use DevTools on selenium 4.0.0-rc-1  but  its giving error before driver initializes  :  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError @djmonki